# WM_SOCKET in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sockets

I plan on using Qt to do my TCP/IP and UDP assignment but I am getting an error which states

```
WM_SOCKET was not declared in this scope
```

`WM_SOCKET` was used in

```
WSAAsyncSelect(socket, this->winId(), WM_SOCKET, FD_ACCEPT|FD_CLOSE);
```

I have included `QMainWindow`, `winsock2.h`, and `ws2tcpip`. I also added the mingw library.

Am I missing an include file or is it something else?

Comment: I included `windows.h` and it still gave the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `WM_SOCKET` message defined by WinAPI. You are supposed to define it yourself.

```
#define WM_SOCKET (WM_USER + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you :D Now I can continue on.